# Is using HTML5 Doctype harmful for Mobile SEO in google?

Tags: html5, google, seo

At this page Google mentioned http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34637&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-1rb2an4c1lcom&cbrank=3

**Q. What mobile markup languages do you support?**

**A.** We support XHTML basic, XHTML Mobile Profile, WML, and cHTML.

Comment: That page lists mobile-specific markup languages. HTML5 is not such a language, so it is not listed.

Comment: what is the mean of support here "What mobile markup languages do you support?"

Comment: People already know that Google can index/search HTML pages, but some mobile sites may not be written in HTML and people would be confused as to whether Google can index them. The purpose of this page is to explain that Google *is* able to index sites not written in HTML, if they are written in one of the listed alternatives.

Comment: Note that HTML is not a *mobile* markup language, that's why it's not mentioned in the list. The question means "What markup languages targeted specifically at mobile devices do you support, in addition to "normal" HTML?"

Answer (score 2):

No. HTML 5 is not harmful to mobile SEO. As mentioned in the comments above, HTML 5 is not a mobile specific markup language so it is not specifically mentioned in that Google help page. HTML 5, like HTML 4, is perfectly fine to use for a mobile website.

If anything, using HTML5 is encouraged as it offers new semantic markup that makes it easier for search engines to decipher the content on the page. As search engines add support for HTML 5 this can only help your mobile SEO efforts.